# Can Voronoi diagrams of lattices be made disjoint?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, integer-lattices, voronoi-diagram

Typically, given a full-rank lattice $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ the Voronoi cell centered at the origin is $$V_0:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:|x|\leq |x-\lambda| \;\forall \lambda\in\Lambda\}.$$
Any such lattice tiles $\mathbb{R}^d$ by translations of $\Lambda$, i.e., $$\mathbb{R}^d = \bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}V_0+\lambda =: \bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}V_\lambda.$$ Clearly, nearby Voronoi regions can overlap on a face (facet of the boundary), but these are Lebesgue measure 0 sets.

My question is: Can we always redefine $V_0$ (or possibly all $V_\lambda$) in such a way that they are all pairwise disjoint, so that $$\mathbb{R}^d = \bigsqcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}V_\lambda?$$

I can convince myself that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, lattices with Voronoi regions that are regular polygons should work this way (e.g., for the square take $V_0 = [0,1)^2$ and for the hexagon take three sides to be closed and the other three to be open, but exclude the endpoint of the two closed edges on the outside).  The cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ works similar to the square I think by using $V_0=[0,1)^3$.

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "redefine." My guess is that you still want cells to be convex and have the same closures/interiors as Voronoi cells. You probably also want invariance under translations by the elements of the lattice. All this can be accomplished.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, my intention there was to take parts of the boundary to be included or excluded such that the interior is the same as the original, and the translations still tile the space, but each copy is disjoint (not just measure 0 overlap) with any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question (as clarified in the comments) is positive. First, a definition:

Definition. Let $C\subset {\mathbb R}^n$ be a convex polyhedron (it does not have to be bounded). Then the *relative interior* of $C$, denoted ${C}^\circ$, is the interior of $C$ in the affine span of $C$. (The affine span is the smallest affine subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ containing the subset $C$.) Concretely, one defines  ${C}^\circ$ as follows: Represent $C$ by a minimal system of linear equations and inequalities. (I.e. a system which has the least (total) number of equations and inequalities.) Replace all inequalities in this system by strict inequalities. The solution set of the resulting system is ${C}^\circ$.

Definition. Suppose that $C$ is a convex polyhedron in $\mathbb R^n$ and $F$ is a face of $C$. Then $F^\circ$ is called an **open face** of $C$.

Now, suppose that $V_0$ is the Voronoi cell as in your question. For every **open** $k$-dimensional face $F$ of $V_0$, $k=0,...,d$, we will do the following. List all the open faces of $V_0$ which have the form $\lambda+ F$ for $\lambda\in \Lambda$, let's call this list $L_F$. For each $F$ keep it as an open face of $V_0$ but remove from $V_0$ all the other open faces in the list $L_F$. Call the result $V_0'$. It is a nice exercise to check the following:

1. $\bigcup_{\lambda\in \Lambda} (\lambda + V_0')= {\mathbb R}^d$.
2. For any two distinct elements $\lambda_1, \lambda_2\in \Lambda$,
   $$
   \lambda_1 + V_0'\cap \lambda_2 + V_0'=\emptyset. 
   $$
   (In other words, $V_0'$ is a *strict fundamental domain* of the lattice $\Lambda$.) This is what you have asked for.

Note: For this to work, you do not need $\Lambda$ to be a (full rank) lattice, it suffices to have a discrete subgroup of ${\mathbb R}^d$. Aside: lattices are usually required to be full rank, at least in my area of math. Also, there is nothing special here about the Voronoi construction, any tiling of $\mathbb R^d$ by convex fundamental polyhedra of $\Lambda$ would work.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and simple argument to answer my question. I indeed assumed the answer would generalize as you suggested, though I arrived at the question through a lattice, and so specified it that way.